# SQL to_date function with case query

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Can SQL Case display operation, return to_date function's result, as its else condition's result?

```
select m.movie_title,c.copy_id,
case 
when r.RENT_RETURN_DATE IS NULL
then 'not returned'
else (to_date(r.RENT_RETURN_DATE,'dd-mon-yyyy') -  to_date(r.RENT_DUE_DATE,'dd-mon-yyyy'))
end AS  "Days Late"
from  copy c,movie m,member mem,rental r
where mem.member_no=r.member_no and c.copy_id = r.copy_id 
and c.movie_id=m.movie_id and mem.member_no=102
```

// (to_date(r.RENT_RETURN_DATE,'dd-mon-yyyy') -  to_date(r.RENT_DUE_DATE,'dd-mon-yyyy')) ----returns an integer //

When I execute the above query, the following error gets displayed:

> Error report -
>
> SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: What data type is `RENT_RETURN_DATE`? If that already is a `DATE` then applying `to_date()` to convert the `date` into a `date` is totally useless (in fact it is a bug waiting to happen)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the two branches in the CASE statement return different types - the `when` returns a character string while the `else` returns an integer. To work around this you can convert the return from the `else` case to a character string:

```
select m.movie_title,
       c.copy_id,
       case 
         when r.RENT_RETURN_DATE IS NULL then 'not returned'
         else TO_CHAR(to_date(r.RENT_RETURN_DATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy') -
                       to_date(r.RENT_DUE_DATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy'))
       end AS  "Days Late"
  from copy c,
       movie m,
       member mem,
       rental r
  where mem.member_no = r.member_no and
        c.copy_id = r.copy_id and
        c.movie_id = m.movie_id and
        mem.member_no = 102
```

Share and enjoy.